# What do the dates on a recently issued Thai visa mean?

Tags: visas, thailand

My partner recently applied for a Thai tourist visa. She expects to arrive on date A, and to leave 5 weeks later on date B - we correctly filled in the application to reflect this (we have photocopies!).

Her passport was returned with two dates on the visa: date C and date D. Date C appears to be the day the embassy received the application (and it is already in the past), and date D is someway between her expected stay dates.

In pictorial form:

```
                            A                 B
Dates applied for:          [-----------------]
Dates on visa:        [------------]
                      C            D
```

So, what do the dates on the visa represent?

- Do they represent the expected stay applied for, and are therefore in error?
- Do they represent a range of dates within which she can enter Thailand, with her exit data being assigned when she does so?

Comment: Is there any text besides the dates?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A [Google Image search for 'thai visa'](https://www.google.com/search?q=thai+visa&hl=is&tbm=isch&gbv=2&sei=KjW6WsXpCIusswH-raOICw#imgrc=YSZCDK45w-xP_M:) shows that such visas have two dates labeled "date of issue" and "enter before". These are likely dates C and D respectively.

"Date of issue" (C) is simply when the visa was granted.

"Enter before" (D) dictates that the visa holder must enter Thailand prior to this date in order to use the visa. After that date, the visa is no longer valid **for entry**. You may still remain in Thailand if you enter before this date and have not stayed longer than allowed by the visa type.

The [type or category](http://www.thaiembassy.com/thailand/thailand-visa-benefits.php) of the visa indicates how long the visa holder can remain in Thailand *after entering*. E.g. a single entry tourist visa (TR) allows up to 60 days.